# How can I integrate a custom Mocha reporter into my test suite to filter out or ignored specific test cases from the test report based on tags?

Tags: automated-tests, mocha.js, chai, custom-tags, mochawesome

I need guidance on integrating a custom Mocha reporter into my test suite to effectively filter out specific test cases from the generated test report based on tags. Specifically, I require a solution to exclude certain test cases, such as those using custom tags, from appearing in the test report.

I want to make this custom tags in js. The version of mochawesome ^7.1.3.

I want where i use custom tags in test cases, after execution in test report, they may not include in test report.